# Textview background color is not changing in android adapter

Tags: android

Hi in the below getting the response from server win_probs getting value 30%,50%,80%.Based on the text percentage changing the background color.

but it is not working with my below code

can any one help me

layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/win_prob"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="30%"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    />
```

Code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(OpportunityAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.account_name.setText(account_names.get(position));
    holder.potential_name.setText(potential_names.get(position));
    holder.contact_name.setText(contact_names.get(position));
    holder.potential_no.setText(potential_nos.get(position));
    holder.location.setText(locations.get(position));
    holder.item_name.setText(item_names.get(position));
    holder.amount.setText(amounts.get(position));
    holder.qty.setText(qtys.get(position));
    holder.win_prob.setText(win_probs.get(position));

    holder.mobile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
            mContext.startActivity(callIntent);
        }

    });

    String winProbsPercent = win_probs.get(position);

if(winProbsPercent.equals("30 %")){
    holder.win_prob.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.red));
} else if(winProbsPercent.equals("50 %")){
    holder.win_prob.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.orange));
} else if(winProbsPercent.equals("80 %")){
    holder.win_prob.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.green));
}
```

Comment: what is win_prob in your code ? One is textview and another one is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply** use `win_probs.get(position)` to get the percentage that you get from server instead of `holder.win_prob` which is a `View` like below:

```
if(win_probs.get(position).equals("30%")){
    holder.win_prob.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.red));
}
```

And you should check the conditions in `if-else` fashion like this:

```
String winProbsPercent = win_probs.get(position);

if(winProbsPercent.equals("30%")){
    holder.win_prob.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.red));
} else if(winProbsPercent.equals("50%")){
    holder.win_prob.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.orange));
} else if(winProbsPercent.equals("80%")){
    holder.win_prob.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.green));
}
```

**Update:** You can also use `setBackgroundResource` to set background

```
if(winProbsPercent.equals("30%")){
    holder.win_prob.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
} else if(winProbsPercent.equals("50%")){
    holder.win_prob.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange);
} else if(winProbsPercent.equals("80%")){
    holder.win_prob.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
}
```

Comment: Try with `holder.win_prob.setBackgroundResource(R.color.whredite);`

Comment: Beside this can you try with debugging that `win_probs.get(position)` provide correct %

Answer (score 1):

change your if like below. you are not comparing string.   `holder.win_prob` is view. you have to get text first.

```
if(holder.win_prob.getText().toString().equals("30%")){
   holder.win_prob.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change a little bit of code to work -

```
if(win_probs.get(position).trim().equals("30%")){
   holder.win_prob.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.red));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use getText().toString() to get the string from the textview and then compare.

```
if(holder.win_prob.getText().toString().equals("30%"))
   holder.win_prob.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.red));
else if(holder.win_prob.getText().toString().equals("50%"))
   holder.win_prob.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.orange));
else if(holder.win_prob.getText().toString().equals("80%"))
   holder.win_prob.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.green));
```